# How to create a bootable USB with Windows?

Tags: centos, windows, live-usb

How would I go about creating a CentOS 7 bootable USB drive with Windows? I've read [the howto page for it](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) and it says that Unetbootin and Universal USB installer won't work for CentOS 7. In addition, I've already tried dd for Windows, and that didn't work properly either - booting from the USB drive resulted in a "Machine Check Error".

Answer (score 3):

It says [in the middle](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey):

> Moreover, the CentOS 7 installer image has a special partitioning which, as of July 2014, most Windows tools do NOT transfer correctly leading to undefined behaviour when booting from the USB key. Applications known (so far) to NOT work are unetbootin and "universal usb installler". **Confirmed as functioning correctly are Win32 Disk Imager and Rawrite32 and dd for Windows.**

So, just use the [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) tool, with the provided images.

iso2usb and Pendrivelinux.com are other options.

Comment: Unetbootin should work. But it didn't. After making a bootable usb, as i restart and enter boot device options, usb does not show at all.

Comment: @MycrofD I updated the answer. Also, Unetbootin was the last option listed, use others first.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make bootable drives on Windows in the past and it has worked well.

You could also try [iso2usb](http://iso2usb.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You caw use [UNetbootin for linux](http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) or if you have some pc with Ubuntu you can use *USB Startup Disk Creator* tool.