# How to create CentOS 7 USB disk on Windows 8?

Tags: centos, windows

How to create CentOS 7 x64 USB disk on Windows 8? this is my question.

Comment: I am sorry, because I don't know where suit for posting my question.

Comment: Please use the search function. This question has been asked and answered before. Here's an example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149152/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-windows

Answer (score -1):

you can use unetbootin: https://unetbootin.github.io/

you can find more answers under https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey (which you could have found by googling 'windows create centos usb boot')

Comment: I have `unetbootin-windows-613.exe`, but **unetbootin** can't create CentOS version 7 USB disk.

Comment: so you may should have mentioned that in your first question and explain whats happening and in which way it is not working!

Comment: We like self contained answers here, without chit-chat. So please expand your answer and use links only to refer to back ground information (ie. the answer should still be useful when the links go dead). `Greetings` have no place in questions or answers on this site.

Comment: sry for this fax pas for the use of an ending in my style of writing. no need to call me a shithead instantly. And for the rest: I gave an answer, a link to more infos and a hint where to search if this link will fail some time. I really dont know whats wrong with that ...